# How to create a radial transparency gradient on a cylinder for a laser render?

Tags: modeling, materials

I am trying to create a cylinder that is transparent on the edges but opaque toward the center. Some kind of radial gradient that is reminiscent of a laser. I also want to apply emission to the cylinder. But the problem I have is I don't know how to the transparency gradient that starts from the center and moves outwards. This is for a still image. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A straight material shader will operate on the outer surfaces only, giving you a "disc" on the top and bottom of the cylinder - if you want it "filled" like a beam, I would suggest using a Volume Shader (works best in Cycles).

Since you are using a simple cylinder, I think the easiest way would be to use a 2D Voronoi Texture set to a scale of 0.1 (Object coordinates), and the randomness set to 0, so it's basically a single dot "extruded" up and down from the midpoint. You can control the size of the "beam" with a ColorRamp (inverted), and control the color and falloff of the beam with a second colorramp (You could do this with 1 ColorRamp instead of course, but it makes it easier to see what's happening with 2). You can also connect an Emission Shader to the Volume socket of the Material Output to make the volume glow:

[image: EmitVolume]